# Pourquoi dit-on « draconique » et pas « dragonique » ?

Tags: étymologie, latin

Quel est l'origine du mot « draconique » ? Pourquoi on a remplacé le « g » par un « c », ça n'a pas de logique !? ne devrait-on pas dire « dragonique » ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Le nom ***dragon*** nous vient du latin ***draco***, qui désigne un dragon, et par extension l’étandard des cohortes romaines, sur lequel figurait un dragon.

Pourquoi construire l’adjectif utilisant la forme latine ?

Le retour vers le latin pour créer des adjectifs existe bien en français, le nom précédant l’adjectif parfois de plusieurs siècles :

- doigt *<sub>ca.1100</sub>* → digital *<sub>1732</sub>* *(en latin digitus → digitalis)*
- nuit *<sub>ca.1119</sub>* → nocturne *<sub>ca.1355</sub>* *(en latin, nox ou noctis → nocturnus)*

C’est ce qui s’est passé aussi pour le couple **dragon-draconique**.

***Dragon*** est attesté sous cette forme déjà en 1080 dans la *Chanson de Roland* :

> Voici qu'ils s'embrasent, les écus aux boucles d'or pur ;
>   Quant au bois des épieux tranchants, il est en pièces.
>   Les hauberts et les heaumes d'acier grincent.
>   Quelle douleur pour les chevaliers de Charles !
>   Des ours, des léopards se jettent sur eux pour les dévorer,
>   Avec des guivres, des serpents, des **dragons**, des monstres
>         semblables aux diables,
>   Et plus de trente mille griffons.

Le dictionnaire du Moyen français de Larousse, où j’ai finalement pu trouver le mot ***draconique*** après avoir échoué dans plusieurs autres dictionnaires, nous indique que ce terme daterait du XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle. Sa forme aurait donc été calquée sur le latin plutôt que sur le français, mais nous l’avons vu, cela se passa aussi pour d’autres adjectifs.

La première attestation serait-elle en [cet extrait](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k11809q/f64.double.r=draconique) dû à la plume d’Eustorg de Beaulieu *(ca.1495-1552)* ? Peut-être...

> Au plus parfond du creux lac plutonique,
>   Ou la puante caterue diabolique
>   Faict residence (et aux plus bas fossez),
>   Soit colloque l'inuenteur des proces.
>   Pour à iamais, en estre pacifique,
>   Dans Acheron l'hydeux neue aquatique,
>   Puisse escouter de Vulcan la musique.
>   Et qu'on ly plonge tant qu'il soit plusque assez,
>         Au plus parfond.
>   Au gouffre ou gist Demogorgon l'antique,
>   Soyent par cruelle morsure **draconique**
>   Ses oz et membres Rompuz et Conquassez,
>   Puis par le chien Cerberus friquassez,
>   Et mys au centre du Chaos tartarique,
>         Au plus parfond.

Le mot n’est guère recensé de nos jours dans les dictionnaires usuels, mais semble par contre fort usité, selon vos dires, dans l’univers de la fantasy.

Doit-on y voir un jugement de valeur porté sur cette culture ? On pourra du moins noter qu’elle a su mettre le doigt sur ce terme datant du siècle de Rabelais, mais un peu tombé dans l’oubli depuis.

En conclusion donc, la forme **draconique** semble avoir été créée selon un processus de création d’adjectifs qui n’est pas inusité en français, et le latin **draco** a subi une corruption de sa prononciation au cours du premier millénaire de notre ère, corruption consommée déjà il y a presque 1000 ans, comme l’atteste la *Chanson de Roland* qui déjà utilise la forme actuelle **dragon**. Pourquoi et selon quel processus l’un est devenu l’autre, le C est devenu G, est cependant une autre question.

Comment: Et du coup, saurais-tu dire pourquoi on a mis un "g" à un moment?

Comment: @Matrix J'ai trouvé [ceci](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1465748/f28.double.r=%22nouvelle%20grammaire%20historique%20du%20fran%C3%A7ais%22) qui donne deux autres exemples de ce type de modification: **gras** de **crassum** et **glas** de **classicum**, et discute de raisons qui eussent pu conduire de l’une à l'autre, bien que les arguments invoqués ne soient pas applicables à **dragon**...

Comment: @Matrix Du moins le C dur et le G dur du français sont deux consonnes gutturales, qui ne se distinguent l’une de l’autre que par le fait que la première n’est pas voisée et que la seconde l’est... Passez de l’une à l’autre est un bond minuscule, que beaucoup font naturellement en prononçant par exemple /anεɡdɔt/ pour **anecdote**.

Comment: Vraiment intéressant. _DHLF_ relève entre autres que _draconien_ remplace _draconique_ depuis le 16e et qu'il est aussi homonyme d'un adj, didactique pour le dragon ; mais _draconique_ n'est plus en usage depuis des siècles. [Google translate](https://translate.google.com/?oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#en/fr/draconic) donne draconique pour _draconic_... Poliment un ré-emprunt (fantaisiste) par calque de G. ? Merci.

Answer (score 2):

Vous n'avez qu'à penser aux mots suivants :

Second, seconder, secondaire, eczéma, où le **c** note déjà le son correspondant au **g**.
   Si on modifie l'orthographe par la suite, c'est pour mieux traduire la diction.
Voilà comment je me l'explique.
   De surcroît la syllabe **con**, prononcée **gon**, est sous l'accent, ce qui favorise le voisement.

Answer (score -1):

Parce que cela vient du grecque, du nom Dracon:

Dracon (en grec ancien Δράκων / Drákôn) est un législateur athénien du viie siècle av. J.-C., appartenant à la classe des Eupatrides (les « bien nés »).

[Dracon](http://Dracon%20(en%20grec%20ancien%20%CE%94%CF%81%CE%AC%CE%BA%CF%89%CE%BD%20/%20Dr%C3%A1k%C3%B4n)%20est%20un%20l%C3%A9gislateur%20ath%C3%A9nien%20du%20viie%20si%C3%A8cle%20av.%20J.-C.,%20appartenant%20%C3%A0%20la%20classe%20des%20Eupatrides%20(les%20%C2%AB%20bien%20n%C3%A9s%20%C2%BB).)

Il ne s'agit pas d'un dragon, une créature mythique.

Comment: justement, toute ma question c'est de savoir où est le lien avec les Dragons? Pourquoi on parle d'un athénien pour nommer tout ce qui est en rapport avec les dragons et leurs cultures dans les univers de fantasy? (pouvoir draconique, langue draconique, dracosire, draco-liche, draco-gardien... etc)

Ca n'a pas de sens qu'il n'y est pas de lien comme ça... (PS : le lien marche pas)

Comment: Une loi draconienne est une loi qui est "dure" et/ou répressive. Evidemment, dans le monde fantaisie (fantasy), dragon peut donner dragonique (et du dico, je passe ici). Je ne puis m'y prononcer formellement.....

Comment: @Matrixe lorsque le mot ou le morphème apparaît dans la fantaisie il s'agit de la racine latine qui avait elle aussi un *c*. La vraie question est d'où vient le *g*. En tout cas, coïncidence entre *draconien* et la créature fantastique.

Comment: @LukeSawczak oui en effet, j'ai vu ça pour le latin : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dragon#%C3%89tymologie mais du coup, pourquoi ce "G" ?!

Comment: @Matrix, parce qu'on peut aussi former un adjectif en ajoutant ique: symbole, symbolique; dragon, dragonique. Cela suit la logique du français.

Comment: La question porte sur le terme *draconique*, qui a trait aux dragons, et non *draconien*, qui vient bien du nom de Dracon.

Comment: I know, thank you. There was no context in the question and I assumed it without bothering to look it up. If the OP had looked it up, it's in every good dictionary.